# redirecting subdomain path to absolute path by htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to do redirect for some paths to another path, for example in the htaccess i have there redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^online\.cbook\.co.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.cbook.co.il/$1 [L,R] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^online.cbook.co.il/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ http://cbook.co.il/user/software?tab=7 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

thie first one worked but the second redirect me to this: http://www.cbook.co.il/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D/

- in this link: http://cbook.co.il/ ,  I'm using CodeIgniter FW

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: i tried this for example: Redirect 301 http://subdomain.domain.com/abc/ http://domain.com/user/link?i=7

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule in .htaccess of `subdomain.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^online\.cbook\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ http://www.cbook.co.il/user/link?i=7 [L,QSA,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^online\.cbook\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.cbook.co.il/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I tried it, and it's not working !! i get 404 page not found.

Comment: see updated answer and make sure these are first 2 rules in your .htaccess

Comment: I insert the lines above and puted it in the first 2 rules but when i enter this link: http://online.cbook.co.il/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D/ i redirect to this link: http://www.cbook.co.il/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D/

Comment: But that is correct. You just want `/abc` to behave diffrently isn't it?